Add item to SP List that contains columns like PeoplePicker, ItemLookup using API
I'm trying to add an item to the SP List using SPHTTPClient from SPFx. And its failing hard.
If I execute it without LookUp columns it will write the data to the List. Current error that I have with this code is:

Cannot convert a primitive value to the expected type 'Edm.Int32'. See the inner exception for more details.

But I'm converting it to number, am I missing something here?
here is the code:
async function AddItemPOST(props: any, itemtoadd: IItem) {
    const url: string = `${props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Item_List')/items`;
    const ItemLocation = 'ItemLocation';
    const ItemCategory = 'ItemCategory';
    const ContactPerson = 'ContactPerson';
    const ItemOwner = 'ItemOwner';
    const listData = {
        __metadata: { type: LIST_ITEM },
        Title: itemtoadd.Title,
        Description: itemtoadd.Description,
        [ItemLocation + 'Id']: itemtoadd.ItemLocation.ID as number, 
        [ItemCategory + 'Id']: itemtoadd.ItemCategory.ID as number,
        [ContactPerson + 'Id']: itemtoadd.ContactPerson.ID as unknown as number,
        [ItemOwner + 'Id']: itemtoadd.ContactPerson.ID as unknown as number,
        shortDescription: itemtoadd.shortDescription,
        Price: itemtoadd.Price,
    };
    const listResponse = await props.context.spHttpClient.post(url, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1, {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
            'Content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
            'odata-version': '' //needs to be here because of parsing of JSON or it will cause an error
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(listData),
    });

    //log the response into console
    if (!listResponse.ok) {
        const errorDetails = await listResponse.json();
        console.log("Error Details:", errorDetails);
        throw new Error(`Error updating item: ${listResponse.statusText}`);
    }
    const listItem = await listResponse.json();
    console.log("List Item Added", listItem);
}

EDIT: ________________
I have troubleshooted and tried the suggestions. Not much progress. Screenshot as ref



Are all people and lookup fields mandatory before saving? I think you are passing blank value to one of the columns in above API call hence you are getting this error.

You were right Ganesh, there was one of them as NaN. Corrected code but still failing to add the Values to List Because of the error.

Is any of the lookup or person/group column allows multiple selections or all of them are single selections?

Get like ListItemEntityTypeFullName here.
const toAdd = {
    __metadata: { type: listItemEntityTypeFullName },
    "Title": "test",
    "MyLookupId": 1
};


Under the Edit of my post, I'm getting the same result as you suggested here.

There are several points you need to check to rectify the error:

make sure to pass integer values in the lookup columns object.
Remove unnecessary unknown and number casting from your object. Instead check the value and then pass appropriate value.
In your persons field, you will have to pass your user's integer id (id are stored from the user information list). These persons fields act as the lookup column in site.

There are several ways to get this user id. One approach you can try is:
const userEmail = "user@example.com";
const userId = await this.context.spHttpClient.get(`${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/siteusers/getbyemail('${userEmail}')?$select=Id`,
    SPHttpClient.configurations.v1
).then(response => response.json()).then(user => user.Id); 

Note: Replace user@example.com with your user's email address.
Also, if you are using any peoplepicker control, it will return user id of the selected user. In this case, you don't have to retrieve their ids explicitly.

I have written it in my answer. You need to make sure when initing the PeoplePicker to set the flag  "ensureUser= {true}" to get ID as number and then you can use that value to write into PeoplePicker Column.

I'm glad your issue is resolved. But you have not provided your full code so I couldn't identify if you are using peoplepicker control or from which package (Fluent UI/pnp).

i have managed to get it working. short guidance
The first problem was it was not getting data from one element of the Component and therefor it was failing. @Ganesh Sanap - thanks for pointing that one out
Second problem was with the data in the ID of PeoplePicker. It was accepting under 'Id' the "i:0#.f|membership| .......@email.onmicrosoft.com". Since the is from IPersonaProps and its importet from '@fluentui/react/lib/components/Persona' i assumed 'Id' would be defined as 'number' and it had somekind converter. That was not the case so i checked the library and found out you need to specify i the  element the ensureUser= {true} flag to get the number of the user into 'Id'.
<PeoplePicker
                    context={props.addPageProps.context}
                    titleText="People Picker"
                    groupName={''}
                    personSelectionLimit={1}
                    showtooltip={true}
                    ensureUser= {true} // returns the Id as number and not some characters
                    required={true}
                    onChange={onChangeContact}
                    principalTypes={[PrincipalType.User]}
                    resolveDelay={1000}
                />

After that i had everything in place and it could write data to the List.
Thanks everyone for your time :)
